# How to shift a dropdown menu to the left?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu below a User info dropdown on my navbar using react bootstrap. Everything is working properly but the dropdown menu is shifted too far to the right causing it to be cutoff by the right side of the screen. I need to shift it to the left but no options seem to be working. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itEiO.jpg)

code for the element

```
    function LoginButtonOrUserInfo() {
        if(state.userInfo === undefined) {
            return (
                <Button className='ml-auto' onClick={onLoginClicked}>
                    Login
                </Button>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <NavDropdown id="navbar-user-info-dropdown" title="User Info" className='ml-auto'>
                    <NavDropdown.ItemText>
                        Welcome, {state.userInfo.firstName} {state.userInfo.lastName}
                    </NavDropdown.ItemText>
                    <NavDropdown.Divider></NavDropdown.Divider>
                    <NavDropdown.Item>
                        <Button onClick={onLogoutClicked}>
                            Logout
                        </Button>
                    </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Just added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `right` property (assuming you're using `position: absolute` or `position: relative`) to specify the distance from the right you'd like to have (example: `right: 3em;`).

Comment: Unfortunately the right property seems to have no effect on the element, but left does.

Comment: So I assume a negative value for `left` works?

Comment: It looks like negative left solves it. I'm not sure why right won't work though

Comment: How did you align the dropdown to the right originally may I ask?

Comment: @RyanMullin I think you have a css that force that element to the right?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try floating left with padding?

e.g.

#dropdownMenu { float: left; padding: 5px; }